# get maximum results per person

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have an `actions` table that has different entries. Each entry contains a `userID` - the ID of the user that made that action.

How could I get only the first 3 actions a user did. I know how to do this in multiple queries or with PHP, but I want to do it in a single MySQL query. Is this possible?

Comment: Do you want to do that for one user or all users at once?

Comment: I want to be able to do it for all users at once! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a `date` TIMESTAMP column for storing the time at which they conducted the action, try this:

```
SELECT * FROM `user_actions` WHERE `userID` = X ORDER BY `date` DESC LIMIT 3
```

`LIMIT 3` denotes retrieving a maximum of 3 values, starting from the first (retrieving the first, second and third result).

**Reference**: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html

Enjoy and good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LIMIT <start>, <count>`, with MySQL :

```
SELECT * 
FROM  user_actions 
WHERE userID = <my id>
ORDER BY date DESC
LIMIT 0 , 3
```

This will return you the 3 first rows of query result (starting at index 0, as specified)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
    FROM table_name 
    WHERE userID='$userid' 
    SORT BY date_column 
    LIMIT 3
```